# Live CD loads and works. Installing shuts down?

Tags: shutdown, live-cd

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105 with 4G of Ram (2x2024).

I have created Live CD's for Ubuntu, Mythbuntu, Fedora and SuperX. Every iso has been confirmed and burned correctly.

I insert the CD and boot from it. I choose "Try xxxx" and it loads the OS fine. I am able to use it for hours without issue.

The moment I try to permanently install any of the OS's, my computer immediately shuts down.

I resintalled Windows and it works fine. I go back to Linux and the shut down problem happens.

This is my first attempt at using any Linux OS, but I love what I get from the Live CD. Can anyone help me? Please talk to me like I know nothing about Linux, as I do not.

Thanks in advance!
Terran

Comment: Can you tell us the exact step in the install process at which the computer shuts down?

Comment: I am now on the computer using Mythbuntu Live CD. I double click "Install" and it brings me to a welcome screen. I choose English, then continue.

I now can choose to install the same OS next to Ubuntu (the same version i am trying to install) or do a clean install. If I choose to dual boot, It immediately shuts down.

Comment: I choose a clean install and it brings me to the install screen. I choose my language, timezone, fill out "who are you" info and it begins copying files. After the files are copied, it goes to Installing system. It usually gets about 75% finished, then powers off. It does not go through any shutdown process, it just turns off.

Comment: Just to make sure - it's not just the screen blanking out from inactivity?

Comment: No, the entire system powers down. I click the power button and had to change the boot order to read from the CD first because now there is no OS recognized. I load the live CD, click try now (because trying to install will just shut down) and can use it as much as I want until I try to install it, then back to the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!!!!!! After flashing a new bios, partitioning and repartitioning, changing NTFS and FAT file systems and learning a crap load about BIOS, I just needed to clean the fan. It was registering 118c! The Fan......